# MapBox GL Marker in Wrong Location Unless Anchor Property Set to Top

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

The MapBox GL marker is placed at the wrong location unless the `anchor` property is set to `top`, which is annoying because now we have to `setOffset` so that the sharp end is pointing the actual location instead of simply using `bottom`. If `anchor` is set to `bottom`, the marker is nowhere to be found on the map.

```
const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
  anchor: 'top' // in right spot only if set to top
})
  .setLngLat([LNG, LAT])
    .addTo(map)
      .setOffset([0,-35]);
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?